# how to send token while post request

Tags: flutter, api, http

have a great day, i have a silly problem, don't mind as i am noob. ok my problem is, i have a token which i received after i login, now i have to post a data but for that i have to include this token in my header, but i don't know how to....

**here is my token, which i received after login as response**

```
{
  "token": "8d18265645a87d608868a127f373558ac2e131a6"
}
```

**Here, i have to implement in flutter**

```
apiData.ApiData app = apiData.ApiData();
  final String apiURl = app.api;
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? email = pref.getString("useremail");
  String? token = pref.getString('token');
  String date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now());
  String time = DateFormat("Hms").format(DateTime.now());
  print(time);
  print(date);
  dynamic response =
      await http.post(Uri.parse(apiURl + "/api/user-log/"), body: {
    'user': email,
    'start_time': time,
    'start_date': date,
  });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data) you can found the following snippet, where the headers are sent with the HTTP request:

```
    Future<http.Response> createAlbum(String title) {
  return http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'title': title,
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add header in the post method as below:

```
 var headers = {
        'authorization': token,
        "Accept": "application/json"
      };

 dynamic response =
      await http.post(Uri.parse(apiURl + "/api/user-log/"),headers: headers), body: {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: this is not working, getting a response of 403 58

Comment: what is the param name you need to put in header?

Answer (score 0):

```
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(apiURl + "/api/user-log/"),
  body: {}
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "<Your token here>",
  },
);
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests)

Comment: this is not working, getting a response of 403 58

Comment: @Saguftaparveen is the server using the Bearer format? If yes, use `Bearer <token>` instead of the plain token